# How to ensure 100% width on my slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css, joomla

I am working on a site but I am not able to get 100% width on my

```
 <div id="top-a"></div> <!-- top-A Element -->
```

I would like to proceed with a jsfiddle, but it might be easier to show you the project.
The slides I am using have a a size of 980px*381px.

The div it is in, has a size of 980px*381px. But still there are appearing margins on the left and the right, and I just don't understand, why. I see that for some reason, the images are resized. But I don't know how to fix it.

The site is:
[Demosite](http://joomla.horyzon.de)

Comment: The page markup is really complicated. You need to just use something like Firebug or the Chrome developer tools to explore the effective styles.

Comment: Did you want it 100% of its parent container? or 100% of the page? It looks as though it has a border which would prevent it from completely filling the div space, hence not allowing edge-to-edge coverage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a margin set

```
.module, #header, #breadcrumbs, #content, #footer {
    margin: 15px;
}
```

change it to

```
.module, #header, #breadcrumbs, #content, #footer {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

EDITED

This may be the rare case that `!important` is required. It is ok to use `!important` when you need to overwrite CSS that is generated by JS and when editing the plugin directly is not an option

Comment: hm... sorry... I responded too quickly.

I changed my settings to: 

    #top-a .module {
      margin: 0;
      margin-left: 10px;
      margin-top: 15px;
    }

But there is still margin. I guess it is because for some reason the image gets resized.

Comment: You need to use `!important` if the CSS is generated or alteredt in anyway by any JS that may be running.